# explain the algorithm for document summarization

Tags: graph, summarization

I want to do a project on document summarization.
Can anyone please explain the algorithm for document summarization using graph based approach? 
Also if someone can provide me links to few good research papers???

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [TextRank](http://web.eecs.umich.edu/%7Emihalcea/papers/mihalcea.emnlp04.pdf) and [LexRank](http://www.jair.org/media/1523/live-1523-2354-jair.pdf).

> LexRank is an algorithm essentially identical to TextRank, and both use this approach for document summarization. The two methods were developed by different groups at the same time, and LexRank simply focused on summarization, but could just as easily be used for keyphrase extraction or any other NLP ranking task.
>
> In both algorithms, the sentences are ranked by applying [PageRank](http://ilpubs.stanford.edu:8090/361/1/1998-8.pdf) to the resulting graph. A summary is formed by combining the top ranking sentences, using a threshold or length cutoff to limit the size of the summary.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_summarization#Unsupervised_approaches:_TextRank_and_LexRank